# SQL: Aggregate by 3 unique column values

Tags: sql

Hi I have this table in SQL.
[image]

I need to aggregate it to a unique SUBMISSIONNUMBER + ATTACHMENT + BOUND.
For each combination of those I need to aggregate sum up the BOUNDPREMIUM and TECHPREMIUM.
After summing up the BOUNDPREMIUM and TECHPREMIUM, I will then calculate BOUNDTECHNICAL which is BOUNDPREMIUM/TECHPREMIUM.

The expected output looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can try the following aggregation query:

```sql
SELECT
    SUBMISSIONNUMBER,
    ATTACHMENT,
    BOUND,
    SUM(BOUNDPREMIUM) AS BOUNDPREMIUM,
    SUM(TECHPREMIUM) AS TECHPREMIUM,
    SUM(BOUNDPREMIUM) / SUM(TECHPREMIUM) AS BOUNDTECHNICAL
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    SUBMISSIONNUMBER,
    ATTACHMENT,
    BOUND;
```